# React hook not triggering re-render with boolean state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a custom hook with a useState holding a boolean value and function that allows me to update the state, I was expecting react to trigger a re render based on the new value but nothing happens

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function useHook() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(false);

  const onClick = (v) => {
    setValue(v);
  };

  return {value, onClick};
}

const Switcher = () => {
  const {value, onClick} = useHook();
  return <button onClick={() => onClick(!value)}>test</button>;
};

export default function App() {
  const {value} = useHook();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('effect', value);
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>result {JSON.stringify(value)}</p>
      <Switcher />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hooks are ways to reuse *behavior, not state*.  In other words, you’re creating 2 `value` states when you call useHook in App and Switcher, respectively. If you want to reuse state without just passing it via props, you’ll need to use something like [redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) or the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate calls to `useHook` which creates to separate states. What you want is one state that gets used in both components. Try passing `value` and `onClick` as props into `Switcher` from the parent component like so:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function useHook() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(false);

  const onClick = (v) => {
    setValue(v);
  };

  return {value, onClick};
}

const Switcher = ({onClick, value}) => {
  return <button onClick={() => onClick(!value)}>test</button>;
};

export default function App() {
  const {value, onClick} = useHook();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('effect', value);
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>result {JSON.stringify(value)}</p>
      <Switcher onClick={onClick} value={value}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```